# Angular - 303 response does not redirect

Tags: javascript, angular, http, http-redirect, http-status-code-303

I have a problem with redirect when getting a 303 response with Location URL from a backend API endpoint. The URL can point to any subpage on my page.

When the browser tries to redirect, I get an error:

> error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', ") at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad
> message: "Http failure during parsing for "

It seems that it treats the HTML response as JSON and tries to parse it, but why?

Thanks for your help.

I don't know what to do in this case.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Angular by default try to parse every response as `JSON`. You need to specify that is not. For example:

```
public getData(): Observable<string> {
  this._http.get<string>('url', {responseType: 'text'});
}
```

Comment: But it will modify first request, that returns Location header - error is from requests made after executing first one

Comment: I understand. Can you please add some relevant code?